# Where to go after Arduino?

Tags: programming, breadboard, custom

I apologise in advance if this question is not right for this Stack or if it has been answered before but here goes. I have been learning C/C++ using the Arduino Uno and have gotten the hang of it now (I have knowledge of other programming languages so it wasn't too difficult to get in the rhythm). I was wondering how I would go about creating a standalone solution if I wanted to display information on four or five displays similar to [These](https://uk.banggood.com/Geekcreit-IIC-I2C-2004-204-20-x-4-Character-LCD-Display-Screen-Module-Blue-Geekcreit-for-Arduino-products-that-work-with-official-Arduino-boards-p-908616.html?akmClientCountry=GB&cur_warehouse=UK). I would pull data from a network to display on them too so I would also need to accommodate an ethernet or WiFi shield.

I appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction that can get me started on my journey to creating some custom embedded systems (if that is indeed what I am describing).

Comment: continue with Arduino for this project

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ESP8266 or ESP32. This makes it easy to transmit data via WiFi. You can also use the Raspberry Pi, which is much more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of much more powerful boards available (especially if you move from ATmega to ARM).  I'm partial to the [Teensy](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) boards myself but Adafruit also makes some nice ARM-based boards.  For example, I'm currently developing a multi-user, Arduino-compatible Unix-ish OS on [one of the latter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3010) (48MHz ARM, 256kB flash, 32kB SRAM) and it runs great.  Honestly, controlling 5 non-graphical LCDs over I²C is should be easily doable on an Uno but if you need more power there are lots of options available.

(No affiliation to either of those companies)

Answer (score 1):

Uno's major limitation is it's 2KB of RAM. If your project can live within that, an Uno can host it.

The display you pointed to is an I2C device and can be bussed, so Uno pin count won't be a limitation. Current might be, and you may need to power the displays independently of the Uno.

The ESP-01 module makes a good Wifi accessory which you can build onto a proto-shield or wire separately. If your Uno is powered at 5v as most are, you'll need to provide 3.3v power to the ESP, and a voltage divider on the ESP's receive pin to reduce the serial input from the Uno to 3.3v.

Update:
Upon re-reading, your title suggests you *want* to move on from an Uno, and you've mentioned a stand-alone solution.

There are many more capable boards available. Arduino Mega is one which would be an easy, almost trivial, transition up from Uno, in flash memory, RAM, and available I/O.

If by "stand-alone" you meant "roll your own", there are any number of how-to projects on the web for rolling your own Atmega 328p-based clone of an Uno.

The direction you take really depends on your project needs and/or your personal preference.